# Why is D2D drawing under D3D11?

Tags: c++, direct2d, direct3d11

My intuition is that if X is drawn before Y then X will be under Y. However, my code seems to always draw things drawn by D2D under things drawn by D3D11. This happens regardless of whether I'm using a depth buffer or not. Why is it doing this and how can I make D2D draw over D3D11 so that I can use D2D to create a GUI overlay?

Here is the smallest reproducible sample I could make:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <d3d11.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#include <wrl.h>
#include <d3dcompiler.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "d3d11.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")
using namespace std;
using namespace Microsoft::WRL;

// Globals

HWND g_hWnd;
// D3D11
ComPtr<ID3D11Device> g_device;
ComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> g_context;
ComPtr<IDXGISwapChain> g_swapChain;
ComPtr<ID3D11RenderTargetView> g_renderTarget;
ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer> g_triangleVertexBuffer;
// D2D
ComPtr<ID2D1RenderTarget> g_renderTarget2D;
ComPtr<ID2D1Factory> g_factory2D;

// Utilities

constexpr const char* VERTEX_SHADER_CODE =
R"(
float4 main(float2 pos : POSITION) : SV_Position
{
    return float4(pos, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
)";

constexpr const char* PIXEL_SHADER_CODE =
R"(
float4 main() : SV_Target
{
    return float4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
}
)";

struct Vector2f
{
    float x, y;
    Vector2f() : x(0.0f), y(0.0f) { }
    Vector2f(float x, float y) : x(x), y(y) { }
};

void AssertHResult(HRESULT hr, string errorMsg)
{
    if (FAILED(hr))
        throw std::exception(errorMsg.c_str());
}

void CompileShaderFromString(string code, string shaderType, ID3DBlob** output)
{
    AssertHResult(D3DCompile(
        code.c_str(),
        code.length(),
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        nullptr,
        "main",
        shaderType.c_str(),
#ifdef _DEBUG
        D3DCOMPILE_DEBUG |
#else
        D3DCOMPILE_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL3 |
#endif
        D3DCOMPILE_ENABLE_STRICTNESS,
        NULL,
        output,
        nullptr
    ), "Failed to compile shader");
}

// Graphics stuff

void InitializeD2D()
{
    // Get swap chain surface
    ComPtr<IDXGISurface> surface;
    AssertHResult(g_swapChain->GetBuffer(
        0,
        __uuidof(IDXGISurface),
        static_cast<void**>(&surface)
    ), "Failed to get surface of swap chain");

    // Create factory
    AssertHResult(D2D1CreateFactory<ID2D1Factory>(
        D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
        &g_factory2D
        ), "Failed to create factory");

    // Create render target
    D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_PROPERTIES rtDesc = D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(
        D2D1_RENDER_TARGET_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        D2D1::PixelFormat(DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN, D2D1_ALPHA_MODE_PREMULTIPLIED)
    );
    AssertHResult(g_factory2D->CreateDxgiSurfaceRenderTarget(
        surface.Get(),
        &rtDesc,
        &g_renderTarget2D
    ), "Failed to create D2D render target");
}

void InitializeD3D()
{
    // Get window dimensions
    RECT rect{};
    GetClientRect(g_hWnd, &rect);
    float width = static_cast<float>(rect.right - rect.left);
    float height = static_cast<float>(rect.bottom - rect.top);

    // Create device, context, and swapchain
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC scDesc{};
    scDesc.BufferCount = 1;
    scDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
    scDesc.BufferDesc.Width = static_cast<UINT>(width);
    scDesc.BufferDesc.Height = static_cast<UINT>(height);
    scDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = 0;
    scDesc.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = 0;
    scDesc.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_UNSPECIFIED;
    scDesc.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_UNSPECIFIED;
    scDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;
    scDesc.Flags = NULL;
    scDesc.OutputWindow = g_hWnd;
    scDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    scDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    scDesc.SwapEffect = DXGI_SWAP_EFFECT_DISCARD;
    scDesc.Windowed = true;
    AssertHResult(D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
        nullptr,
        D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
        NULL,
#ifdef _DEBUG
        D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG |
#endif
        D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT,
        nullptr,
        NULL,
        D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
        &scDesc,
        &g_swapChain,
        &g_device,
        nullptr,
        &g_context
    ), "Failed to create device and swapchain");

    // Create render target
    ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> backBuffer;
    AssertHResult(g_swapChain->GetBuffer(
        0,
        __uuidof(ID3D11Resource),
        static_cast<void**>(&backBuffer)
    ), "Failed to get back buffer of swapchain");
    AssertHResult(g_device->CreateRenderTargetView(
        backBuffer.Get(),
        nullptr,
        &g_renderTarget
    ), "Failed to create render target view");

    // Bind render target
    g_context->OMSetRenderTargets(
        1,
        g_renderTarget.GetAddressOf(),
        nullptr
    );

    // Bind viewport
    D3D11_VIEWPORT viewport{};
    viewport.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    viewport.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    viewport.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
    viewport.TopLeftY = 0.0f;
    viewport.Width = width;
    viewport.Height = height;
    g_context->RSSetViewports(
        1,
        &viewport
    );
}

void InitializeD3DTriangle()
{
    // Create vertex buffer
    Vector2f vertices[3] =
    {
        Vector2f(-0.5f, -0.5f),
        Vector2f(0.0f, 0.5f),
        Vector2f(0.5f, -0.5f)
    };
    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC vbDesc{};
    vbDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    vbDesc.ByteWidth = static_cast<UINT>(sizeof(Vector2f) * 3);
    vbDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_WRITE;
    vbDesc.MiscFlags = NULL;
    vbDesc.StructureByteStride = sizeof(Vector2f);
    vbDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DYNAMIC;
    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA vbData{};
    vbData.pSysMem = vertices;
    AssertHResult(g_device->CreateBuffer(
        &vbDesc,
        &vbData,
        &g_triangleVertexBuffer
    ), "Failed to create vertex buffer");

    // Bind vertex buffer
    const UINT offset = 0;
    const UINT stride = sizeof(Vector2f);
    g_context->IASetVertexBuffers(
        0,
        1,
        g_triangleVertexBuffer.GetAddressOf(),
        &stride,
        &offset
    );

    // Create and bind vertex shader
    ComPtr<ID3DBlob> vsBlob;
    ComPtr<ID3D11VertexShader> vertexShader;
    CompileShaderFromString(
        VERTEX_SHADER_CODE,
        "vs_4_0",
        &vsBlob
    );
    AssertHResult(g_device->CreateVertexShader(
        vsBlob->GetBufferPointer(),
        vsBlob->GetBufferSize(),
        nullptr,
        &vertexShader
    ), "Failed to create vertex shader");
    g_context->VSSetShader(
        vertexShader.Get(),
        nullptr,
        NULL
    );

    // Create and bind pixel shader
    ComPtr<ID3DBlob> pxBlob;
    ComPtr<ID3D11PixelShader> pixelShader;
    CompileShaderFromString(
        PIXEL_SHADER_CODE,
        "ps_4_0",
        &pxBlob
    );
    AssertHResult(g_device->CreatePixelShader(
        pxBlob->GetBufferPointer(),
        pxBlob->GetBufferSize(),
        nullptr,
        &pixelShader
    ), "Failed to create pixel shader");
    g_context->PSSetShader(
        pixelShader.Get(),
        nullptr,
        NULL
    );

    // Set topology
    g_context->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY::D3D10_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_TRIANGLELIST);

    // Create input layout
    ComPtr<ID3D11InputLayout> inputLayout;
    D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC ilDesc{};
    ilDesc.AlignedByteOffset = 0;
    ilDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT;
    ilDesc.SemanticName = "POSITION";
    ilDesc.SemanticIndex = 0;
    ilDesc.InputSlot = 0;
    ilDesc.InputSlotClass = D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA;
    ilDesc.InstanceDataStepRate = 0;
    AssertHResult(g_device->CreateInputLayout(
        &ilDesc,
        1,
        vsBlob->GetBufferPointer(),
        vsBlob->GetBufferSize(),
        &inputLayout
    ), "Failed to create input layout");

    // Bind input layout
    g_context->IASetInputLayout(inputLayout.Get());
}

// Windows

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (msg)
    {
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProcW(hWnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}

void InitializeWindow(HINSTANCE hInst, int width, int height)
{
    // Register window class
    WNDCLASSEXW wc{};
    wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEXW);
    wc.hCursor = LoadCursorW(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wc.hInstance = hInst;
    wc.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wc.lpszClassName = L"MainWindow";
    wc.style = CS_OWNDC;
    RegisterClassExW(&wc);

    // Adjust width and height to be client area instead of window area
    RECT rc{};
    rc.left = 0;
    rc.top = 0;
    rc.right = width;
    rc.bottom = height;
    constexpr auto ws = WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW;
    AdjustWindowRectEx(
        &rc,
        ws,
        false,
        NULL
    );

    // Instantiate and show window
    g_hWnd = CreateWindowExW(
        NULL,
        L"MainWindow",
        L"Window Title",
        ws,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        CW_USEDEFAULT,
        static_cast<int>(rc.right - rc.left),
        static_cast<int>(rc.bottom - rc.top),
        NULL,
        NULL,
        hInst,
        nullptr
    );
    ShowWindow(g_hWnd, SW_SHOW);
}

// Driver code

void Update()
{
    // Begin frame
    g_renderTarget2D->BeginDraw();

    // Clear screen to black
    D2D1_COLOR_F bgColour = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    g_renderTarget2D->Clear(bgColour);

    // Draw D3D triangle
    g_context->Draw(
        3,
        0
    );

    // Draw D2D rectangle
    D2D_RECT_F rect{};
    rect.bottom = 500;
    rect.top = 300;
    rect.left = 100;
    rect.right = 700;
    D2D1_COLOR_F rectColour = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    ComPtr<ID2D1SolidColorBrush> brush;
    g_renderTarget2D->CreateSolidColorBrush(
        rectColour,
        &brush
    );
    g_renderTarget2D->FillRectangle(
        rect,
        brush.Get()
    );

    // End frame
    AssertHResult(g_swapChain->Present(
        1,
        NULL
    ), "Failed to present swapchain");
    g_renderTarget2D->EndDraw();
}

int APIENTRY wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE prevInst, LPWSTR cmdArgs, int cmdShow)
{
    InitializeWindow(hInst, 800, 600);
    InitializeD3D();
    InitializeD2D();
    InitializeD3DTriangle();

    // Run message loop
    while (true)
    {
        // Handle windows messages
        MSG msg{};
        PeekMessageW(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE);
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            break;

        // Quit is escape is pressed
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_ESCAPE) & 0x8000)
            break;

        // Do frame
        Update();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you want to control the draw order, then you shouldn't be drawing both at the same time. Call ``Draw``, then ``BeginDraw`` / ``EndDraw``. Don't mix them as you have no idea when Direct2D is actually flushing commands to the context in your code, and you have no explicit indication of when Direct3D is done drawing to the render target.

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn I separated the draw calls like you said and now EndDraw is failing with "the object is not in a correct state to process the method". Any suggestions?

Comment: @ChuckWalbourn nvm, I just made a small mistake while rearranging code. Your comment answered my question. Why don't you post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to control the draw order, then you shouldn't be drawing both at the same time. Call `Draw`, then `BeginDraw` / `EndDraw`. Don't mix them as you have no idea when Direct2D is actually flushing commands to the context in your code, and you have no explicit indication of when Direct3D is done drawing to the render target.

> You can of course call Direct3D's `Flush` which will force all work on the GPU to complete, but it's horribly inefficient to call it every frame.